# JavaMail - Delay notification in SMTP - office 365

Tags: java, outlook, smtp, office365, jakarta-mail

I am using the JavaMail to connect and verify the username and password in office 365.
I use the following java code to check the connectivity,

```
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
            
            System.out.println("Before Session... #################################################");
            
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("username_xxxx@xxx.com", "password_xxxxx");
                }
            });
            System.out.println("After Session... #################################################");
            session.setDebug(true);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            System.out.println("Before Connection... #################################################");
            transport.connect();
            System.out.println("After Connection... #################################################.");
            if(transport.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("Connected Successfully : " + transport);
                System.out.println("#################################################");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Connected : " +  transport);
            }
            transport.close();
```

Mostly 70% of the time, transport.connect() works as expected where the greeting message (220) is received in less than 100ms but there are sometimes (say after 3 hours of the application is deployed in webserver), transport.connect() takes more than 2 minutes to send the greetings message

```
2020-08-23 11:38:16,930 ERROR [stderr] (default task-415) Before transport connection ::: Sun Aug 23 11:38:16 UTC 2020
2020-08-23 11:38:16,931 INFO  [stdout] (default task-415) DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
2020-08-23 11:38:16,933 INFO  [stdout] (default task-415) DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false
2020-08-23 11:40:27,657 INFO  [stdout] (default task-415) 220 BL0PR02CA0082.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sun, 23 Aug 2020 11:40:27 +0000
```

I enabled the session logs and we could see the 11:40:27,657 log (220 BL0PR02CA0082.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready) takes a long time to receive.

I did some surfing and found the root cause is due to the SMTP server https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.2.1 where the greetings message 220 can be send in delay!

How can we avoid this delay is my question ?

Anyhelp is appreciated!

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Exhange probably dislikes your code for some reason. Talk to the administrator to hear if there is anything in the logs

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, Actually we use the smtp.office365.com which is the global SMTP server, Where can I get those logs?

Comment: No idea.  If you give Microsoft money, you most likely have support. This is a support question.

Comment: How many connection attempts occur in 3 hours of the application uptime?  Maybe you are being throttled due to excessive connection attempts or dangling connections as you are not using a try/finally.

Comment: @jmehrens, transport.close() is properly closed, Also I try to remove the close() from the code and try it but the issue is not reproducing consistently. Also FYI, the other API's are working as expected only this transport.connect() takes a long time